# Need help identifying a php error

Tags: php

I've been following a simple php tutorial on youtube and have ran into an error. I know that the error 'unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)' means that php isn't expecting '=>', but in the video it all looks the same. Here is my code:

index.php

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
require 'db/connect.php';
```

connect.php

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'app');

echo $db => connect_errno;

//if($db=>connect_errno){

//}
?>
```

I commented out error_reporting, because the part of the tutorial was showing how to catch an error number by deliberatly putting the wrong db table name in the connect.php. However I noticed that its not working.

full error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ';' in
```

any help would be appreciated, as i literally can't see a single difference between the code when stripped down and the code from the tutorial. Thanks for your time. oh and i'm using wamp server on the local host, it seems to connect to the db just fine when i comment out the $db=>connect_errno.

Comment: Try single arrow like this "->"

Comment: `->` for object references, `=>` for array elements. You're trying to use an object reference.

Comment: If you really copied the video code verbatim, that video contains totally invalid PHP code.

Comment: you're right, thank you! This is what i get for trying to code at the same time as watching the video, the screen is too small to make out the difference :/

Comment: Hehe, we've all been there once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written wrong syntax

```
echo $db => connect_errno;
```

If need to check the connection error, than you have to write

```
echo $db->connect_errno;
```

or something like

```
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
```